# Web Services design

Tags: web-services

Company A has async pooling based webservice for notifications. Company B checks for notifications. Every time when it reads new notifications A deletes them from the system. Thus subsequent read requests return only new notifications. There is also requirement for the client B to interrupt the connection if there is no response within 30 sec.

This causes one potential problem: Due to unexpected slowness it is possible for A get the request deleted a notification and send the response back while B is already interrupted the connection. Under this scenario notification gets lost. Now one can argue that the core problem lies within operation realm (the HTTP response must be delivered withing 20 sec ) still on practice it is not always feasible.

How to design B (the client) to avoid this problem?

One way I can see is to do not delete the notifications by A and make B be aware of its state, so that it knows starting from what ID it needs to process notifications, but that presumes that ID will be sequential. Which is controlled by A. Even if B defines its own sequence A still has to be altered to return it back.

Are there any other approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web services in general are unreliable enough that it's rarely a good idea to make a "read" request serve double-duty as a "delete" request, especially without the client's knowledge. There is just too much risk of a connection dropping or timing out. There is no way to get around this *only* by modifying the client, because it's the server that is at fault here - the way it's designed is fundamentally unsuited for a web service.

I think you're on the right track with the incrementing IDs idea. The client knows (or can be modified to know) which notifications it's received, so if it can supply the ID of the last message it's received when it polls for notifications, the server should be able to respond based on that ID.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like Company A's webservice should be synchronous instead of asynchronous.  If that is not possible, it may be a good idea to send a "ACK"-like response to a new Company A webservice that indicates a specific notification was received (by Company B) and can be deleted.